# RServe Connection Issue

Tags: r, linux

need help with setting up connection from Tableau to a server where R is installed. Installed R and Rserve in linux.Started the Rserve from R console using

```
library(Rserve) 
Rserve()
```

In Tableau trying to set up connection and then test connection by providing Server name and port as 6311 I get below error

> "Connected party did not properly responded after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond"

tried `chkconfig iptables off` and `service iptables stop` but no use.

Comment: 1. check from remote R session using `RSclient` package. 2. check telnet connection, see [Rserve/faq](https://rforge.net/Rserve/faq.html) - search for `telnet`.

Comment: I am getting below message telnet mke-dwetlap-d10 6311 -> "Connecting To mke-dwetlap-d10...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6
311: Connect failed"